# Create Camel project with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-camel

I am trying to create a camel project using only the Eclipse IDE. Apparently, the newest versions of Eclipse have Maven support out of the box, so there i no need to install the [m2e plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/). Still, I cannot create a camel project using Eclipse (even with m2e plugin) because the camel archetypes don't even appear ! What am I missing?

I decided to take 4 screen shots to save your time and and so you can understand the problem:

Eclipse version and m2e plugin details
[image: Eclipse version and m2e plugin details]

Using the Maven wizard to create a new project
[image: Using the Maven wizard to create a new project]

Creating a default project
[image: Creating a default project]

Using the filter to search for camel archetypes
[image: Using the filter to search for camel archetypes]

At first I assumed that the problem was mine, and that I was typing something wrong in the filter. But after searching for all the archetypes available, I still could not find anything related to camel.

And thanks for the help guys, you're all being great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try another way around. Generate with maven Camel project and import it into eclipse:

Instructions for creating Camel project from maven are on [Camel site](http://camel.apache.org/camel-maven-archetypes.html)

And then use:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

to generate eclipse workspace that you will import.

If you want to do it from eclipse you should add catalog for [Camel archetype](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group) , so you should  go to: `Window / Preferences / Maven / Archetype / Add Remote Catalog...`

Or

when you are creating a maven project press "Add Archetype" button, and enter following values:

- groupId:org.apache.camel.archetypes
- artifactId:camel-archetype-java
- version:2.12.1
- URL:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact

Comment: I really insist in doing it with Eclipse only. I have added the Camel archetype as you said, but apparently I still get a white list of nothingness. Here is how I added the archetype [camel-archetype](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/785815/5.camel-archetype.png) and here is the list that I see [camel-archetype-filter](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/785815/6.camel-archetype-filter.png)

Comment: Try also maven repository catalog: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.archetypes

Comment: Adding this link has the exact same effect. I wonder if I have to download every existing archetype into my machine so I can choose from them after. This however sounds incredibly stupid for a solution that is advertised as working "out of the box".

Comment: I've just imported it and it finds it. So when you are creating a maven project press "Add Archetype" button, and enter following values: 
groupId:org.apache.camel.archetypes
artifactId:camel-archetype-java
version:2.12.1
URL:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact
This worked for me!

Comment: Thanks it worked now for me as well. Quick notice though, in the URL field I used URL:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.archetypes otherwise it wont work (not for me at least)